# Is it possible to get a regular value from state and not as Observable angular Ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data

I'm wondering if I can get a regular value type from NGRX state and not an Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `State` class [extends `BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/state.ts#L19):

```js
export class State<T> extends BehaviorSubject<any> implements OnDestroy { ... }
```

I think you can get the current state by injecting `State` and calling `state.getValue()`.